# add a calculated column to the active record in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im defining a search in the database to return some rows. Im then calculating a distance in the controller. I want to be able to reference the calculated distance (d) in my view like the other columns. How would I do this?

This is my attempt at pushing the calculation into the model:

In the welcome controller:

```
      def search


    @coordinates = Geocoder.coordinates(params[:address])

        lat = res[:latitude].to_f
        long = res[:longitude].to_f


    @places = Place.within_miles_of(lat: lat, long: long)




  end
```

In the places model:

```
    class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :user_id, presence: true
#belongs_to :user
validates_presence_of :title, :address, :postcode, :category, :phone


geocoded_by :postcode
after_validation :geocode, :if => :postcode_changed?

belongs_to :user

    def self.within_miles_of(coords = {})


        ids = []

        Place.select("id,latitude,longitude").where("category='#{params[:category]}'").each do |res|

            lat = res[:latitude].to_f
            long = res[:longitude].to_f

            d = Geocoder::Calculations.distance_between(@coordinates,[lat,long])

            puts d
            ids << res[:id] if d <= 5

        end

        if ids.any?
            @places = Place.where("id in #{ids}".gsub("[","(").gsub("]",")")).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 9)

        else
            @places = []
        end

    end

end
```

I seem to be getting the following error:

undefined local variable or method `res'

Comment: your full logic should go to the model, and then return the calculated value, and store it in a instance variable like `@d`, and then use `@d` inside the view.. You are READY for *SQL Injection*. If you don't want, change `where("category='#{params[:category]}'")` to `where("category= ?", params[:category])`..

Comment: its for a search value so i cant store it in the database. I need to do it dynamically

Comment: What does `Geocoder::Calculations.distance_between` look like? That should ideally be run on the database level.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: geocoder is a gem for calculating distances, it pings google for a distance calculation

Comment: I cant store the calculated field in the database, the user is searching their postcode against the places model. The distance number will be different for each value they enter so they cant be stored.

Comment: That's not what I'm suggesting. You should not be performing these calculations in Ruby, your database will have better support, and will be faster, and less problematic. You shouldn't have to loop over every single record and filter out ones where distance < n. That's incredibly inefficient and will cripple performance as the table grows.

Comment: what database are you using and what version of rails?

Comment: What he is referring to is http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_query

Comment: i think thats over complicating the solution. im using postgrsql and rails 4

Comment: If you're using the geocoder gem, you might find this tutorial helpful: http://www.synbioz.com/blog/search_by_location_with_geocoder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Class Method**

You'll be best reading up on [class vs instance methods](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/) - basically you're trying to add to your `model` is a `class method` to pull the required data:

```
#app/models/place.rb
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
   def self.within_miles_of(category, page = 1)
      ids = []

       Place.select("id,latitude,longitude").where(category: category).each do |res|

            lat = res[:latitude].to_f
            long = res[:longitude].to_f

             d = Geocoder::Calculations.distance_between(@coordinates,[lat,long])

             puts d
             ids << res[:id] if d <= 5

        end

        @places = ids.any? ? Place.where("id in #{ids}".gsub("[","(").gsub("]",")")).paginate(:page => page, :per_page => 9) : @places = []

   end
end


#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
Class Controller < ApplicationController
    # ...
    @places = Place.within_miles_of(category)
end
```

--

**Fix**

Your main problem is you're trying to call `category = #{params["category"]}`. `params` are not available in the model; so you'll have to pass the category in the `arguments` too (same goes for the `pages` param)

Being honest, I think your code can be DRYed up a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class method to the model that takes whatever params you need and returns the calculated value.

```
def self.within_miles_of(coords = {})
  # Calculate here
end
```

Comment: im not sure I understand

Comment: Move the logic you have in your controller for finding places within a certain distance of the coords into your `Place` model by adding the method above. This will allow you to use that method in your controller by calling it as `Place.within_miles_of(lat: 41.1236, long: 63.3784)`. You can have that return an array of `Place` models that you can then use in your view. Rails uses skinny controllers and fat models. If it is something you plan to reuse a lot you could put it in a `Module` and `include` it in your model. Checkout Rails 4 concerns if you want to do that.

Comment: I have given that a go, have updated the question to include the attempt

Comment: any ideas? not sure where to go now :s

Comment: You're using `params` in the model, `params` is only available in the **controller**.  You can pass in the categories as a parameter to the method.  Are you getting an error?  If so please post that as well.